# After one-click-installing Ruby on Rails on DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I created a digital ocean droplet, and one click installed ruby-on-rails. I SSHed into the server, and found that I have one ruby on rails project called `example`. This application seems to run when I type the IP address of the droplet into google.

I want to upload my own website, so I `git cloned` a repository from bitbucket, which contained a finished ruby on rails website. I tried running `rails db:create`, and it failed. There was a lot of stuff not installed yet, all of which I had thought that one click install would handled. Once I installed bundler and ran `bundle install`, the installation failed once it got to the `nokogiri` gem. When I ran `bundle install` on the `example` project, installation also failed when it reached `nokogiri`, but the example app still ran in the browser without errors.

So I deleted the example project, leaving my rails website as the only project in the `rails` directory on my droplet. When I refreshed the page, I got an error saying that the `example` application was missing. I renamed my website directory to `example`, and refreshed the page and now I get this error:

```
Errno::EACCES

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/rails/example/tmp/cache
```

I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated. If you have some articles or documentation links explaining how to deploy a ruby application to a droplet that had ruby on rails installed by default, I'd love to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with your rails installation. You must have used sudo while installing.

You can change permission to get rid of this issue using chmod.

Comment: I should've used sudo when I installed rails? I did the one-click install, meaning that DigitalOcean installed rails, not me. Should I remove my website directory and try git cloning it again? or do you think I should just delete my droplet and one click install rails again?